# How to check set of numbers against another set

Tags: bash, shell

For fun I want to check generated lotto numbers against the winning ones to see how many tickets it would have taken to win.

I have a generator which generates x tickets, and I have a separate checker which reads in from a file. I want to combine the two as currently doing it separately is slow due to all the disk read and writes. My question is, what's the best way to do this?

```
./generator 10 >test10.txt

#!/bin/bash

tickets="$1"

function gen_numbers {

for ((z = 1; z<=tickets ; z++)); do
     i=0
     used=( 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
     printf "$z ";
     for (( ; i<6;  )); do
        x=`echo $[ 1 + $[ RANDOM % 59 ]]`;
        if [ ${used[$x]} -eq 0 ]
        then
            printf "$x ";
            i=$((i + 1))
            used[$x]=1
        fi
     done;
     printf "\n"
done;
printf " \n"; }

############################
if [[ -z $tickets ]]  ; then
    get_tickets
    gen_numbers
else
    gen_numbers
fi
```

Check tickets
./checker

```
awk ' FILENAME=="win.txt" {
           for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) { win[$i]=1}

        }
        FILENAME=="test10.txt" {
           tmp=0
           for(i=1; i<= NF; i++) { if($i in win){ tmp++} }
           if(tmp >5) {arr[$0]=tmp}
        }
        END {for ( i in arr) {print arr[i], i}} ' win.txt test10.txt
```

Ideally I want my code to simply display how many tickets it has generated/checked, and stop once it has matched all 6.

Answer (score 0):

What about something as simple as avoiding the intermediate file writing? You can use process substitution for this purpose:

```
awk '....' win.txt <(./generator 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's two files of numbers, (one per line), standard utils should work:

1. `grep -w -f win.txt test10.txt`
2. In sorted order:  `sort win.txt test10.txt | uniq -d`